# Nuxt.js generate and Three.js - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js, netlify, nuxtjs

I’m using Nuxt.js to create a full static landing page and i’m also using Three.js to render a 3d Globe in the page, everything works correct in dev mode and production mode in local, but when i try to deploy to **netlify** using **yarn generate** to create a full static site, it shows this error:

`function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { SyntaxError: Cannot use    import statement outside a module at new Script (vm.js:88:7) at createScript (vm.js:261:10) at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:10) at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:15) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18) at /Users/herow/Web-Projects/arpen-technologies/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:77662 at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:/external "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js":1:0) at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0) at Module.37 (pages/index.js:22:25) at __webpack_require__ (webpack/bootstrap:25:0) at Module.38 (pages/index.vue:21:0)`

This makes references to the imports that i’m doing in the Three.js component:

`import * as THREE from 'three'`

`import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'`

`import { EffectComposer } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js'`

`import { RenderPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js'`

`import { GlitchPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/GlitchPass.js'`

Here i’m importing the plugins from the **jsm folder**, i have tried importing this from the js folder but then i get **THREE is not defined error.**

I don’t know what does it mean. Please guide me.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the following line to the build section in the Nuxt.config.js file:

```
build:{
transpile:[“three”]
}
```

That should do the trick!